# Trying to parse just time with DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, parsing, localtime

Having trouble parsing only a 'time of day' for a LocalTime variable using DateTimeFormatter. Tried several different formats, but not seeing what I'm missing (was thinking since I'm using DateTimeFormatter I need to have a date component, but I use it with just LocalDate no problem and the documentation says it supports LocalTime).

Thanks in advance for any help/links identifying my mistake that causes the exception.

Replicated with this SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

public class SSCCE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){          
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String word = "";

                word = "1200am";
//              System.out.println(LocalTime.parse(word.toLowerCase(),  DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME).toString());
                System.out.println(LocalTime.parse(word.toLowerCase(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hhmma")).toString());
//              System.out.println(LocalTime.parse(word.toLowerCase(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hmma")).toString());
//              System.out.println(LocalTime.parse(word.toLowerCase(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmma")).toString());
//              System.out.println(LocalTime.parse(word.toLowerCase(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("Hmma")).toString());
//              System.out.println(LocalTime.parse((CharSequence)word.toLowerCase(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hhma")).toString());

            word = "8PM";
            System.out.println(LocalTime.parse(word.toLowerCase(), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME).toString());           
            }
        });
    }
}
```

...and I get this stack trace:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: 
>   Text '1200am' could not be parsed at index 4
>       at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:194
>   7)
>       at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1849)
>       at java.time.LocalTime.parse(LocalTime.java:441)
>       at SSCCE$1.run(SSCCE.java:14)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.ja
>   va:75)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java
>   :201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:11
>   6)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java
>   :105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Answer (score 4):

You should convert it to uppercase instead of lowercase because the `DateTimeFormatter` will only parse uppercase `AM`/`PM`:

```
System.out.println(LocalTime.parse(word.toUpperCase(),
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hhmma")).toString());

// will print 00:00
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was some stupid thing I was missing!